# How to draw selection box on SWT Table?

Tags: java, swt, selection, box

I've been googling around for a possible solution, but nothing similar came up. So, I need to ask if it's possible.

I want in a SWT `Table` widget to select multiple items with my mouse when dragged. Just like in native-OS.

I have setup my `Table` with `SWT.MULTI`, but this works only for keyboard.

I am curious, since SWT uses native-OS calls to draw its GUI, why this function is not implemented out-of-the-box in the `Table` widget?

This is already implemented in **Angry IP Scanner** utility software as you can see in the attached picture.

I would appreciate any kind of help.

[image: Selection box in a SWT Table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [Tracker](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FTracker.html) widget to achieve similar behavior. Here is a simple POC to showcase what can be done.

```
public class TableShellExample {

  Display d;

  Shell s;

  TableShellExample() {

    d = new Display();
    s = new Shell(d);

    s.setSize(250, 200);

    s.setText("A Table Shell Example");
    s.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Table table = new Table(s, SWT.MULTI | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);

    TableColumn tc1 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.CENTER);
    TableColumn tc2 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.CENTER);
    TableColumn tc3 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.CENTER);
    tc1.setText("First Name");
    tc2.setText("Last Name");
    tc3.setText("Address");
    tc1.setWidth(70);
    tc2.setWidth(70);
    tc3.setWidth(80);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);

    TableItem item1 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    item1.setText(new String[] { "Tim", "Hatton", "Kentucky" });
    TableItem item2 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    item2.setText(new String[] { "Caitlyn", "Warner", "Ohio" });
    TableItem item3 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    item3.setText(new String[] { "Reese", "Miller", "Ohio" });
    TableItem item4 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    item4.setText(new String[] { "Rey", "Miller", "Texas" });
    TableItem item5 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    item5.setText(new String[] { "Json", "Miller", "Alabama" });

    if((table.getStyle() & SWT.MULTI ) != 0 && (table.getStyle() & SWT.FULL_SELECTION ) != 0)
    table.addListener(SWT.DragDetect, e -> {

      TableItem item = table.getItem(new Point(e.x, e.y));
      int startIndex = -1;
      int endIndex = -1;
      if (item != null) {
        startIndex = table.indexOf(item);
        Tracker tracker = new Tracker(table.getParent(), SWT.RESIZE);
        tracker.setStippled(true);
        tracker.setRectangles(new Rectangle[] { new Rectangle(e.x,e.y,1,1) });
        if (tracker.open()) {
          TableItem finishedItem = table.getItem(table.toControl(Display.getDefault().getCursorLocation()));
          if (finishedItem != null) {
            endIndex = table.indexOf(finishedItem);
          }
        }
        tracker.dispose();
        table.deselectAll();
        if (startIndex != -1 && endIndex != -1) {
          table.setSelection(Math.min(startIndex, endIndex), Math.max(startIndex, endIndex));
        }
      }

    });

    s.open();
    while (!s.isDisposed()) {
      if (!d.readAndDispatch())
        d.sleep();
    }
    d.dispose();
  }

  public static void main(String[] argv) {

    new TableShellExample();
  }
}
```

Comment: That was EXACTLY what I need! Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: I want to add a second listener to the table. When mouse.down to do something. Although, it seems that only one mouse event can be dispatched; either mouse.down or mouse.dragged. How can I do it? I tried addListerer(SWT.MouseDown | SWT.DragDetect, e -> { ...} but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share this just in case someone else finds it useful.

This function is already implemented (without having to add any extra "fancy" code as I thought) just by adding an `SWT.Selection` Listener to your `Table` and that's all!

```
table.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        // to-do...
    }
}
```